# mongodb index. how to index a single object on a document, nested in an array

Tags: mongodb, indexing, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

I have the following document:

```
{
    'date': date,
    '_id': ObjectId,
    'Log': [
        {
            'lat': float,
            'lng': float,
            'date': float,
            'speed': float,
            'heading': float,
            'fix': float
        }
    ]
}
```

for 1 document, the `Log` array can be some hundred entries.

I need to query the **first** and **last** `date` element of `Log` on each document. **I know how to query it, but I need to do it fast, so I would like to build an index for that**. I don't want to index `Log.date` since it is too big... how can I index them?

Comment: This seems somewhat unclear to me what you want and if it is related to indexing at all. Are you saying you need to find the first (minimum) and last (maximum) date within that array? And since it is an array are they possibly inserted in order, or even could do with being ordered that way?

Comment: I updated my question. I know how to index it, but I would like to access it very fast, so I want to index it... and I don't know how

Comment: Then how is the answer that I gave not very fast? Please read and see what matches your conditions.

Answer (score 1):

In fact it's hard to advise without knowing how you work with the documents. One of the solutions could be to use a sparse index. You just need to add a new field to every first and last array element, let's call it `shouldIndex`. Then just create a sparse index which includes `shouldIndex` and `date` fields. Here's a short example:

Assume we have this document

```
{"Log": 
    [{'lat': 1, 'lng': 2, 'date': new Date(), shouldIndex : true}, 
    {'lat': 3, 'lng': 4, 'date': new Date()}, 
    {'lat': 5, 'lng': 6, 'date': new Date()}, 
    {'lat': 7, 'lng': 8, 'date': new Date(), shouldIndex : true}]}
```

Please note the first element and the last one contain shouldIndex field.

```
db.testSparseIndex.ensureIndex( { "Log.shouldIndex": 1, "Log.date":1 }, { spar
se: true } )
```

This index should contain entries only for your first and last elements.

Alternatively you may store first and last elements date field in a seperate array.

For more info on sparse indexes please refer to this [article](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/index-sparse/).

Hope it helps!

Comment: Worth noting here that if this indeed a reflection of what the data does look like, then in order to tag in such a way you would need to **find** the **first** and **last** dates before you could even apply a sparse index. Which kind of leads me to my point.

Comment: Yes, thanks. I do know how to access the first and last elements. This was not the scope of my question. I will try it out. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

So there was an answer about indexing that is fundamentally correct. As of writing though it seems a little unclear whether you are talking about indexing at all. It almost seems like what you want to do is **get** the **first** and **last** date from the elements in your array.

With that in mind there are a few approaches:

**1**. **The elements in your array have been naturally inserted in increasing date values**

So if the way all writes that are made to this field is done, only with use of the [$push](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/update/push/) operator over a period of time, and you **never** update these items, at least in so much as changing a date, then your items are already in order.

What this means is you just get the first and last element from the array

```
db.collection.find({ _id: id },{ Log: {$slice: 1 }});    // gets the first element
db.collection.find({ _id: id },{ Log: {$slice: -1 }});   // gets the last element
```

Now of course that is two queries but it's a relatively simple operation and not costly.

**2**. **For some reason your elements are not naturally ordered by date**

If this is the case, or indeed if you just can't live with the two query form, then you can get the first and last values in [aggregation](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/method/db.collection.aggregate/), but using [$min](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/min/) and [$max](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/max/) modifiers

```
db.collection.aggregate([

    // You might want to match first. Just doing one _id here. (commented)
    //{"$match": { "_id": id }},

    //Unwind the array
    {"$unwind": "$Log" },

    //
    {"$group": { 
        "_id": "$_id",
        "firstDate": {"$min": "$Log.Date" },
        "lastDate": {"$max": "$Log.Date" }
    }}

])
```

So finally, if your use case here is getting the details of the documents that have the first and last date, we can do that as well, mirroring the initial two query form, somewhat. Using [$first](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/first/) and [$last](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/last/) :

```
db.collection.aggregate([

    // You might want to match first. Just doing one _id here. (commented)
    //{"$match": { "_id": id }},

    //Unwind the array
    {"$unwind": "$Log" },

    // Sort the results on the date
    {"$sort": { "_id._id": 1, "Log.date": 1 }},

    // Group using $first and $last
    {"$group": { 
        "_id": "$_id",
        "firstLog": {"$first": "$Log" },
        "lastLog": {"$last": "$Log" }
    }}

])
```

Your mileage may vary, but those approaches may obviate the need to index if this indeed would the the only usage for that index.